# Capture regex negative lookbehind using Pandas

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, regex-lookarounds

Given these strings:

```
START-h1-/h1-p-code-/code-code-/code-code-/code-/p-h1-/h1-ol-li-code-/code-p-code-/code-/p-/li-li-code-/code-/li-p-code-/code-/p-li-code-/code-/li-p-code-/code-/p-li-code-/code-code-/code-p-code-br-postmaster@domainname.com-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-/postmaster@domainname.com-/code-/p-/li-br-li-/li-li-p-code-/code-/p-/li-/ol-p-b-/b-/p-ul-li-/li-li-code-/code-/li-li-code-/code-/li-li-a-/a-/li-/ul-p-a-/a-/p

START-p-code-/code-/p-p-/p-h2-/h2-p-/p-p-code-/code-/p-p-code-/code-code-/code-code-/code-code-/code-code-/code-code-/code-code-/code-/p-p-code-/code-/p-ul-li-strong-/strong-code-/code-/li-li-strong-/strong-code-/code-/li-li-strong-/strong-code-/code-code-/code-/li-li-strong-/strong-code-/code-/li-li-strong-/strong-code-/code-/li-li-strong-/strong-code-/code-/li-li-strong-/strong-code-/code-/li-li-strong-/strong-code-/code-code-/code-/li-li-strong-/strong-code-/code-/li-li-strong-/strong-code-/code-/li-/ul-p-code-/code-/p-h3-/h3-p-code-/code-/p-p-code-/code-code-/code-br-br-code-br-br-/code-code-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-br-/code-/p-h3-/h3-p-/p-p-code-/code-/p-ol-/ol

START-h1-/h1-p-a-/a-/p-p-a-/a-/p-p-strong-/strong-br-/p-p-strong-/strong-br-/p-h1-/h1-ul-li-code-/code-/li-li-ul-br-li-/li-li-code-/code-/li-/ul-/li-/ul-h1-strong-/strong-/h1-ol-li-strong-/strong-/li-li-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-/li-li-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-/li-/ol-h1-strong-/strong-/h1-ol-li-strong-/strong-ul-br-li-code-/code-/li-li-code-/code-/li-/ul-/li-br-li-strong-/strong-/li-li-code-/code-/li-/ol-h1-a-/a-/h1-p-br-/p

START-h1-/h1-p-/p-p-/p-ul-li-a-/a-/li-li-a-/a-/li-/ul-p-strong-/strong-br-/p-h1-/h1-ol-li-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-br-br-img-/li-br-li-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-br-br-img-/li-br-li-strong-/strong-br-br-img-/li-br-li-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-br-br-img-/li-br-li-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-br-br-img-/li-br-li-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-br-br-img-/li-br-br-li-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-br-br-img-/li-br-li-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-br-br-img-/li-/ol-p-strong-/strong-strong-/strong-/p-h1-a-/a-a-/a-/h1-p-br-/p-p-/p
```

And this regex pattern:

```
((?<!\/li|-[ou]l)-li|(?<!\/li|\/[ou]l)-\/[ou]l)
```

How do I capture the part to the left of the `-li` back to the next `-` character?

As you can see here in a demo https://regex101.com/r/nrNVt9/1 the pattern currently only captures `-li` but I need to capture/extract, for example: `-/p-li`, `-ol-/ol`, `-br-li`, etc.  Whatever is to the left of the -li moving left to the next "-" and including that then stopping.

Note: I'm working with python/pandas and str.extract so the pattern has to be balanced otherwise I get the error:

```
error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

The negative lookbehind is confusing me I think.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `-/?(?:p|li|[ou]l)-li-` https://regex101.com/r/735grk/1 Or only the part on the left using a capturing group `(-/?(?:p|li|[ou]l))-li`  https://regex101.com/r/GLypJu/1

Comment: The regex pattern has to do this: Find -li when not preceded by -ol nor -ul nor /li OR find -/ol or -/ul when not preceded either /li nor -/ol or -/ul.  It does this but it does not capture the bit that precedes the -li OR -/ol or /ul.  I want to capture the -li or -[ou]l PLUS the bit in the negative lookbehind.

Comment: Try it with separate lookbehinds `(?:(?<!-[ou]l)(?<!li)-li|(?<!li)(?<!-/[ou]l)-/[ou]l)` https://regex101.com/r/7A0pVB/1

Comment: I'm hoping it's possible to match when it's not something (and that's working), but then record what it was actually there.  Is that possible?

Comment: Simpler example:  Given: cat
bat
fat
sat
mat

Find **at** when not preceded by c, f, nor m but allow me to know there was bat and sat found (not two matches for "at" with no idea what was found.

Comment: Perhaps like this using a negative lookahead `(?!-[ou]l|li)(-[^-\r\n]+)-li|(?!-/[ou]l|li)(-[^-\r\n]+)-/[ou]l` https://regex101.com/r/kVi6Xz/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208443/discussion-between-mdr-and-the-fourth-bird).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a lookbehind, you could use a negative lookahead `(?!` and 2 capturing groups with an alternation for both the alternatives.

```
(?!-[ou]l|-/li)(-[^-\r\n]+)-li|(?!-/[ou]l|-/li)(-[^-\r\n]+)-/[ou]l
```

**Explanation**

- `(?!-[ou]l|-/li)` Assert what is on the right is not `-ol`, `-ul` or `-/li`
- `(-[^-\r\n]+)-li` Capture in group 1 matching any char except `-` and match `-li`
- `|` Or
- `(?!-/[ou]l|-/li)` Assert what is on the right is not `-/ol`, `-/ul` or `-/li`
- `(-[^-\r\n]+)-/[ou]l` Capture in group 1 matching any char except `-` and match either `-/ol` or `-/ul`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dpOH2Z/1)